# remove leading(left) zeroes in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

the content of my file is

```
0001,02,003
004,0005,06
0007,8,9
```

I read the file as

```
val file1 = spark.read.textFile("file1").map( x => x.toLowerCase())

file1.collect
    res7: Array[String] = Array(0001,02,003, 004,0005,06, 0007,8,9)
```

I want to remove the leading zeroes.
I know we use ltrim but it is used only in case of strings to remove spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just cast them to `Int` and you should be fine

```
val file1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file1").map( x => x.split(",").map(_.trim.toInt).mkString(","))
file1.collect
//res0: Array[String] = Array(1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9)
```

Comment: great to hear that @pooja

Comment: is there a way to remove leading zeroes only from the first element of each line and keeping rest of the data same

Comment: just convert the first element of the splitted array to int then and you would get what you want

Comment: can u please help me with the syntax..code that i am using and getting error is val file2 = file1.map( x => x.split(",").map(y => y(0).trim.toInt).mkString(","))
<console>:47: error: value trim is not a member of Char
       val file2 = file1.map( x => x.split(",").map(y => y(0).trim.toInt).mkString(","))
                                                              ^

Comment: `val file1 = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file1").map( x => {val splitted = x.split(","); splitted.head.toInt+","+splitted.tail.mkString(",")})` thats all and you should be fine